# istanbul.yml not being picked up by istanbul

Tags: istanbul

I'm using istanbul.js and it says I can create a istanbul.yml to configure it, but it's not being picked up automatically. Do I need to configure somewhere that I have created it?

Running istanbul like:

```
istanbul cover --report cobertura _mocha test/
```

works ok.

Thanks! Guillermo.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're putting it in the root of the project folder, and that it starts with a "."

The correct filename is `.istanbul.yml`.